# Creating an extra desktop in C#

Tags: c#, virtual, desktop

I've seen some applications that create virtual desktops. I want to create one.

However, I do not know how you would do this, or even it it is possible.

How do I create a virtual desktop/monitor in C#?

Comment: Someone should reopen this question. @Will

Comment: @user1981338: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [CreateDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in order to create full functional dekstop on windows os:

> Creates a new desktop, associates it with the current window station
>   of the calling process, and assigns it to the calling thread. The
>   calling process must have an associated window station, either
>   assigned by the system at process creation time or set by the
>   SetProcessWindowStation function.

Would invite your attention also on interesting article from *CodeProject*:

[Desktop Switching](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7666/Desktop-Switching)

In general multidektop environment already exists in `Windows Os` for many years, but never has been "visible" via any multi-dektop application implemented by MS itself. 
For some reason MS never, as much as I'm aware of, implemented multidesktop app.

If I'm not mistaken, beginning even from *WindowsNT* familly OSes, you already have a second desktop. When you press `Ctrl+Alt+Del` the screen that appears, in reality, is on another, fully functional, windows desktop.

Comment: In conclusion, you need to use interop, as this can't be done directly with C#...

Comment: I can't seem to find the Desktop class anywhere. Got any pointers?

EDIT: Nevermind I'm stupid, it's in the site's download

Comment: @Samyn: it's inside the code. download the code present.

Comment: When I run a game, switch back to my original desktop, switch back to the new desktop, It becomes black and exits. What can cause this? The desktop becomes inactive?

Comment: @DreTaX: it's hard to say, could be literally anything. check for some possible ways to retrieve a error code, exception..something. To get feedback from it.

Comment: I have been literally trying to make that game focused while not bothering me work since a time. I will keep looking...